# How unique is socket.id?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm building an application where I'd like a unique identifier for every connection for the duration that the app is running and I'm wondering if socket.id works for this.  E.g. if user 1 disconnects from the application, user 2 who connects later shouldn't have the same socket.id that user 1 had before even though user 1 is no longer connected.  Are socket ids unique for the entire time socket.io is listening to the server?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming that you're using `socket.io@0.9.x` (which is the present version in NPM), the code that generates a new id for each connection/client [can be found here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/0.9/lib/manager.js#L741-L758).

I think that you can safely assume that each socket id is going to be unique.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at socket.io's code, it seems that the id of a user uniquely identifies a socket client. See, for example, the code for [Socket.connect](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/lib/socket.js#L243):

```
Socket.prototype.onconnect = function(){
  debug('socket connected - writing packet');
  this.join(this.id);
  this.packet({ type: parser.CONNECT });
  this.nsp.connected[this.id] = this;
};
```

On the last line, the id is used in a hash that keeps track of connected sockets. Since you need your ids to be unique, each id is then unique as long as the server has not been restarted

Comment: But this doesn't show that id's won't be recycled, which is what the OP wants to know.