# Uniqueness of socket.id of websocket in distributed web applications

Tags: node.js, sockets, distributed-computing

Suppose you want to scale your web application that relies on `websocket` technology (e.g `Socket.io` library). You have multiple servers and you are using a shared database (e.g `Redis`) to have a communication with these servers.

In this case you store socket ids of each socket connection in that db. My question is:

> Is it possible that two users that are connected to two different
>   servers get the same socket.id so that you couldn't differentiate them?

In this case, if you want to notify a specific user, you will do it for another user too!

- How it is possible?
- If it is possible how people solve this problem in real world use cases ?
- Is there any trick in programming or in the design ?

**EDIT**

I want to emphasize on *distributed environments*.

Comment: Some relevant information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20962970/how-unique-is-socket-id). It sounds as though you generally wouldn't get conflicts doing that, but I'd say you probably will just have to test it. As I'm sure you know, documentation on socket.io is scarce at best.

Comment: The code to generate socket id's has been modularized to [`base64id`](https://github.com/faeldt/base64id). It might also be worthwhile to see how [`socket.io-redis`](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis) handles these things.

Comment: @pay You mean there is a chance to have a duplicated socket.id?