# Socket.io identifier each user

Tags: node.js, angular, sockets

I'm creating an application ( skype like ) with angular 6 + socket.io . 
the idea that i need to store the socket of each user connect to server , to be able to send direct message later .
so i go ahead by saving the socket.id for each user and 
the problem i found that all the user have the same socket.id , i tried with that code and it keep giving the same socket.id .

i'm using 2 local pc for test :
   PC1 : 192.168.1.3 (host the server also)
   PC2 : 192.168.1.2

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
     console.log('a user connected RT');
     console.log("user socket : "+socket.id);
    });
```

i wonder how i can track each user and be able to send him direct message.
i'm using :

- "socket.io": "^2.1.1"
- "socket.io-client": "^2.1.1"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20962970/how-unique-is-socket-id. It generates unique socket id for each connection.

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya exactly that's what supposed to be , but in my case i got the same socket.id for booth PC .

Comment: did yiu try socket.io ver 0.9?

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya , nope i will try it and back to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for some reason i can get the socket.id only before any other listener after the connection listener

```
    // work 
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
         console.log('a user connected RT');
         console.log("user socket : "+socket.id);
    });






      // not working 
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
             console.log('a user connected RT');
io.on('join',function(){
console.log("user socket : "+socket.id);
})

        });
```